# How to use NSMaxXEdge in Cocoa app with Swift (Xcode 6)?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I've tried to create a Cocoa app which uses `NSPopover` internally. One of the popover's method is `showRelativeToRect: ofView: preferredEdge:`, which triggers an popover in Cocoa app.

If you use Objective-C in Xcode 5.1, you can execute the method with the method above, like this:

```
[popover showRelativeToRect: sender.bounds ofView: sender preferredEdge: NSMaxXEdge];
```

However, when I tried to use the method in Swift in Xcode 6, the message `Use of unresolved identifier 'NSMaxXEdge'` was shown when I wrote the following method, which is just a rewrite of the Objective-C method above:

```
popover.showRelativeToRect(sender.bounds, ofView: sender, preferredEdge: NSMaxXEdge
```

So where is the `NSMaxXEdge` gone? The official documentation says it is of type `NSRectEdge`, but what is the `NSRectEdge`? The doc doesn't link to `NSRectEdge` page.

Also, Xcode 5 documentation also says it is `NSRectEdge`, but again, no link exists there. So how can I know about what it is all about?

And finally, if `NSMaxXEdge` is no longer available in Xcode 6, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Foundation/NSGeometary.h` of 10.10 SDK:

```
typedef enum {
    NSMinXEdge = 0,
    NSMinYEdge = 1,
    NSMaxXEdge = 2,
    NSMaxYEdge = 3  
} NSRectEdge;
```

So it should be `NSRectEdge.from(2)` or `NSRectEdge(2)` or just pass `2` will be fine.

If you try this:

```
    println("NSRectEdge.max: \(NSRectEdge.max)")         // 9223372036854775807
    println("NSRectEdge.from(2): \(NSRectEdge.from(2))") // 2
    println("NSRectEdge(2): \(NSRectEdge(2))")           //2
```

You will know that `.max` was actually the max positive signed Int for 64-bit.

(Tho, I can't be sure since it's not really mentioned in documentation anywhere.)

Answer (score 1):

`NSRectEdge` has a static var called `max`. I think you should just use that. For example:

```
popover.showRelativeToRect(rect, ofView: view, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.max)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Then why does it differ from the way it's used in Objective-C? Maybe it is struct in Swift while it is alias in Objective-C, or something like that? How/where did you know about the fact that "`NSRectEdge` has a static var called max"?

Comment: This is not correct. max just refers to Int's static var. x43x61x69 shows that the value does not refer to anything useful in terms of possible NSRectEdges

Answer (score 0):

(The below is true for beta 5 (developing for 10.9). Your mileage may vary.)

Above, you get a solution that works - passing 0-3 where the function calls for a NSRectEdge. I'd like to pick up on

> how can I know about what it is all about?

The documentation indicates that NSRectEdge is bridged with CGRectEdge, but trying to pass in CGRectEdge led to an error of

> CGRectEdge is not convertible to NSRectEdge

NSRectEdge.from(2) or NSRectEdge(2) - as suggested above - come back with the error that

> NSRectEdge has no accessible initializers

When you type NSRectEdge into Xcode, however, it shows two types:
CGRectEdge (which in this case is useless, see above) and Int.

I'm afraid that you need to guess that NSRectEdge is an enum when you see it both called as a string and defined as an int; but from there to looking up its definition in the framework is a logical step; as is guessing that you will have four values, one for each edge.

Incidentally, there seems to be an internal modulo operation going on somewhere - when you pass it '4', you get NSMinXEdge again and so on.